# Why are departure rates of $M/M/c$ queues not equal to service rate $\mu$?

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, stochastic-processes, queueing

I think this issue should have an answer somewhere but I could not find in any materials. In every textbook I read about $M/M/c$ queueing systems, it is always acknowledged from the beginning that the departure rates for that queue are defined as $\mu_n = n\mu$ if $n \le c$, and $\mu_n = c\mu$ if $n \ge c$, where $\mu$ is the mean service rate and $n$ is the number of customers in the system.

What is the intuitive meaning of this definition? And is there any strict proof for that too?

What if we have two different service rates (both follow exponential distributions) with mean $a$ and $b$ ? For example, there are 2 servers, and currently there are 2 customers with different service rates $a < b$ occupying the 2 servers. How can we know the departure rate at each state $\mu_1, \mu_2, \mu_3... $ in this case?

Comment: You can prove that if $n$ servers are currently occupied, then the time until the next departure is exponentially distributed with mean $(n\mu)^{-1}$. In other words, the time until the *first* service completion, out of the $n$ customers currently in service, is exponentially distributed with rate $n\mu$. So the reason for this highly convenient fact is the assumption that the service times are exponentially distributed and therefore totally memoryless.
A very good book to learn about all of this is Tijms H.C., A First Course in Stochastic Models, Springer 2003.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have a single queue of $n$ people, in a shop each waiting to but their items. Suppose I have $c$ servers (i.e. cashiers).

If $n<c$, and on average, it takes $\mu$ times units (say minutes) for a single servers to serve a single customer. If I have say $c = 5$ servers then I can serve up to $n = 5$ people at once, so my service rate will be up to $5\mu$; I serve $5$ customers every $\mu$ minutes. If I only have $n=2$ customers at once, then my service rate is only $2\mu$, even if my capacity is $5\mu$. If I have $n=10$ customers my service rate will only be $5\mu$ because my workers can only serve $5$ people at once.